# Grainy Texture Look on Shapes with Sketch 3

Tags: sketch-app

There is a dark, grainy look on this image (view below) that I want to replicate. **How do you create this texture in Sketch 3 app?**

[image]

I tried to add the grainy texture on the shape by adjusting the "Fills" with a grainy texture, and the result looks like this (view below):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can't you reduce the contrast of the effect by using a texture that's less different to the fill, or reduce the texture's opacity?  I think your effect is too strong.

Also the texture in the example doesn't fill the entire shape. I think perhaps you could add another shape without the texture over your shape, and apply a blur effect to it.

I don't have access to Sketch, but in Illustrator I got this by applying a blur to a shape over the textured shape. I'm pretty sure you could do something similar in Sketch.

[image]